# Successfully transpiled jsx won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

My gulp file is doing the heavy lifting for me.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// gulpfile.js
// Gulp is our task runner. Currently being used to transpile ES6 and React.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('babelify');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
const buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Transpile the ES6 and React code.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('js', () => {
    return browserify({ entries: ['react-src/LobbyChatReact.js'] })
    .transform(babel, {presets: ["react", "es2015"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('LobbyChatReact.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts/react-build'));
});
```

So this is successfully taking the jsx file at /react-src/LobbyChatReact.js, transpiling it, and outputting the result at /public/javascripts/react-build/LobbyChatReact.js.

One thing I should note is that this output file is like 20,000 lines long. Is that normal? I'm pretty sure browserify is the culprit here.

My jsx file is standard. Don't think it's my problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Lobby extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Lobby />, document.getElementById("test"));
```

So here is my ejs file containing the div that I'm trying to render this react component onto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lobby Chat</title>
<script type="text/jsx" src="javascripts/react-build/LobbyChatReact.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my route for good measure.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get lobby chat.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
router.get('/lobbychat', function(req, res) {
    res.render('LobbyChatReact');
});
```

So since my jsx is being transpiled successfully, I'm not sure why I can't render it. I don't get any errors, just a blank screen.

Here is a clue. If I include something like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
```

in the head of my ejs file, then it WILL render. The thing is, it takes like 3 seconds to load and just about freezes my laptop it's so darn slow. I think it has something to do with the 20,000 line output file? I'm already using babel when I transpile, so how is this cdn doing work on my already transpiled file?

Comment: Try removing `type="text/jsx"`.

Comment: Good idea, but I already tried text/jsx, text/babel, and nothing. None of those options worked. By the time it's transpiled though, the type should just be javascript, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could you check your console for errors?

Comment: I did check. So I found the solution after hours of trying. I had to use type=text/javascript as I suspected, because the code was indeed transpiled to vanilla js. At that point, I had to move the script tag to the bottom of the body instead of the head. Voila! That combination of tweaks worked. Thanks for suggesting I mess with the type.